# How Do I add data in the notepad .txt file in C#?

Tags: c#

I am able to write new data into the .txt file. But, it comes as the replacement of the existing data.
So, how can I add new data to the file by keeping the existing data already present in the .txt file.
I have been using `System.IO` namespace and `StreamWriter` to edit data.

```
StreamWriter EditEmployeeDetail =
    new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\FoodDeliverySystem\Employee_details.txt");
EditEmployeeDetail.Write(temp_Emp_Det);
EditEmployeeDetail.Close();
```

Comment: StreamWriter has many constructors. Did you read about its documentation? If you read it you would find this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_

Comment: StreamWriter does not have an append mode so you need to use another method for writing.  Try File Class : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 4):

Use the static [File class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8) instead

```
string path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\FoodDeliverySystem\Employee_details.txt";
File.AppendAllText(path, temp_Emp_Det);
```

`AppendAllText` opens, writes and closes the file all with one call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the StreamWriter you want to append:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a stream to the file with the `Append` option set.

```
StreamWriter EditEmployeeDetail = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\FoodDeliverySyste\Employee_details.txt", true);
```